# Angular 6 - Fast way to clean up LESS

Tags: angular, angular6, less

So we have a bunch of generic less files that we import into our component less files. During initial development I think we were a little too liberal about our imports and now when I look at our final main.js bundle it's almost 8MB.

The possible quick solutions I'm seeing are either tree-shaking or some way to determine if nothing in a less file is being used in the component (kind of like how intellisense tells you an import isn't being used). Problem is I've got no clue on if solutions exist for either of these and I'd really rather not have to manually go through each component looking to see if I can clear an import.

Any thoughts or suggestions on what to do here?